# Find row with min/max value for each day in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with multiple days data in it (only one day shown here for brevity):

```py
                       Charge
2022-01-03 13:19:02    99.5
2022-01-03 13:20:03    95.0
2022-01-03 13:21:02    64.2
2022-01-03 13:22:02    91.8
2022-01-03 13:23:02    99.5
```

I want to be able to find the row with the min and max value so that I can get the exact time of the min and max charge. If there are multiple, I will just select the first occurrence. i.e.:

```py
                       Charge
2022-01-03 13:19:02    99.5
2022-01-03 13:21:02    64.2
```

I have tried using:

```py
df_bat_chrg_min = df['Battery State of Charge'].groupby(df.index.day).min()
df_bat_chrg_max = df['Battery State of Charge'].groupby(df.index.day).max()
df_bat_chrg = pd.merge(df_bat_chrg_max, df_bat_chrg_min, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This generates:

```py
            Max Charge  Min Charge
2022-01-03  100.0       96.5
```

The index name, however, doesn't include the exact time of the event, as exemplified in the second code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and
[`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for indices by minimal and maximal values, convert to `Series` and select original `DatetimeIndex` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = (df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.day)['Charge']
               .agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax']).stack()].sort_index())
print (df1)
                     Charge
2022-01-03 13:19:02    99.5
2022-01-03 13:21:02    64.2
```

If need aggregate new columns:

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.index.day)['Charge'].agg(['min','max', 'idxmin', 'idxmax'])
print (df2)
    min   max              idxmin              idxmax
3  64.2  99.5 2022-01-03 13:21:02 2022-01-03 13:19:02
```